# Redux Saga stops after error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm combining a set of Sagas, ( some `takeEvery` and `takeLatest` ) from different modules and using `yield all(sagas)` to combine them all in RootSaga.

Everything works, without issue. I catch errors inside the Sagas themselves. But, now the requirement is to catch errors at RootSaga level too, in any case, someone misses catching a problematic part.( Actually, I'm working on boilerplate for a multi-team project. )

I see, if someone is not using try catch to catch a problematic part, then the error is propagated and Saga completely stops working after that. Sagas won't watch anything thereafter.

What I want to do is, let other Sagas run without issues and RootSaga to be working thereafter, keep watching as usual. How can I achieve this?

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all(sagas);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the `rootSaga` you are getting back a task. That task has a `done` property which is a promise. So:

```
const rootSagaTask = reduxSagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

rootSagaTask.done.catch(error => {
  // Error here is a fatal error.
  // None of the sagas down the road caught it.
});
```

Comment: I get the console log of the error in `rootSagaTask.done.catch`, but Sagas stops listening thereafter. I'm having a button to make an API call with a value in a textbox. Now, nothing happens when I click the button after an error occurred with a previous button click.

Comment: Well, that is the expected behavior. If there is an error and you don't catch it the sagas should stop working. This is a nice mechanism that protects you from probably bigger problems.

Comment: Oh, but what if I just want to log the error and keep continue, rather the whole app stop working?

Comment: In this case you have to handle the error where it occurs. Or in other words the developer that is responsible for that problematic part should design his/her solution like that so it continues working in case of error. It's not a rootSaga's job to deal with that.

Comment: @Krasmir I see, thanks for clearing it up. Anyway, isn't there any way I can have some kind of a wrapper for this, just to wrap a Saga inside a try catch and attach it to Root Saga may be?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of such solution.

Comment: For convenience during development, it should work to call `reduxSagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)` again in the error handler to restart the root saga. I believe this would reset any state that existed in the previous saga though (progress in sagas, delays, debouncing, etc.). Also ignores the fact that an error occurred which could certainly have the potential to be dangerous on prod. The same reasoning from React error boundaries applies here https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#new-behavior-for-uncaught-errors

Answer (score 5):

For v1 use

```js
rootSagaTask.toPromise().catch(e => {

});
```

Comment: Please, try to give more complete explanation about your solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After much thinking about this problem, I implemented my own middleware function. Like:

**Middleware function:**

```
 * @function errorFallback
 * @param {CallableFunction} sagaFunction
 * @param {object} action
 * @description
 * * Captured exceptions which is occurred from saga function.
 * * Whenever any exception occurred from saga functions, whole sagas will be destroyed.
 * * We can use this function to save sagas from die.
 * @example
 *    export function* getSagaData() {
 *      yield all([
 *        takeLatest('GET_SAGA_DATA', errorFallback, getSaga),
 *      ]);
 *    }
 */

function* errorFallback(sagaFunction, action) {
  try {
    yield sagaFunction(action);
  } catch (error) {
    // exception log to your server
  }
}

export default errorFallback;
```

**Uses**

```
export function* loadSampleSaga() {
  try {
    const response = yield post('/create', {
      name: 'test',
      salary: '123',
      age: '23',
    });
    yield put(sampleSuccessAction());
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(sampleFailureAction());
    throw err;
  }
}

export function* getSampleSaga() {
  yield all([takeLatest('GET_SAMPLE_SAGA_DATA', errorFallback, loadSampleSaga)]);
}
```